# How to pass object argument to browser.execute method?

Tags: node.js, browser, webdriver-io

I am trying to use WebdriverIO's `execute` method to pass a browser object like this:

```
describe('reference', () => {

    it('test browser', () => {      

        browser.execute(function(){
            console.log('BROWSER:', browser);
        });             
    });
});
```

But there is an error:

> Failed: unknown error: browser is not defined

How can I pass my browser object to a custom function?

Answer (score 1):

Any code inside of `execute` is run inside the browser itself, meaning that the `browser` object isn't available.

You can pass the `browser` object in, but because it won't have access to all the rest of WebdriverIO, I'm guessing it won't work like you're hoping. Regardless, here's the code for that:

```
browser.execute(function(wdioBrowser){
    console.log('BROWSER:', wdioBrowser);
}, browser);
```

You do have access to the normal DOM though. So if you want to find an element, you can do:

```
browser.execute(function(){
    console.log('Element:', document.querySelector('.my-selector'));
});
```

If you're looking for more details, I have an 8 minute video on it in [my WebdriverIO course](https://learn.webdriver.io/) (#23 in the list).